# RESTful API and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

Not entirely sure if this is a beginner question, but I can't seem to find any detail information regarding how to use APIs with rails.

For the past months I've been to a few hackathons / interviews where one of the tasks is to use APIs to return some meaingful data and make something cool. I looked online for documentations on how to integrate API to websites using rails, but can't seem to find any good ones.

How exactly do I integrate APIs with rails and where should I put them? Some examples of APIs that I would like to play around with are Zappos and Parse, both are REST APIs

https://parse.com/docs/rest

http://developer.zappos.com/docs/api-documentation/

If there are some links that you would like to share, that would be awesome!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that lets you send http requests to a remote URL can be used to implement your own wrapper for a restful API, but I personally prefer to use the rest-client gem:

https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client

If you wanted to take a more hands on approach, you can just go straight for the Net:HTTP library in Ruby:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html